# What is the grok pattern for this jenkins log?

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Can you please help me with the grok pattern for this jenkins sample data or log. The log is only a single line.

```
hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher launch\nSEVERE: Unable to launch the agent for dot-dewsttlas403-ci\njava.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in /opt_shared/iit_slave/jenkins_slave/workspace\n\tat hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:144)\n\tat hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:109)\n\tat hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:84)\n\tat hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:74)\n\tat hudson.util.TextFile.write(TextFile.java:116)\n\tat jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl$WriteAtomic.invoke(WorkspaceLocatorImpl.java:264)\n\tat jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl$WriteAtomic.invoke(WorkspaceLocatorImpl.java:256)\n\tat hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3042)\n\tat hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)\n\tat hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)\n\tat hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)\n\tat hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n\tSuppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to dot-dewsttlas403-ci\n\t\tat hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1743)\n\t\tat hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)\n\t\tat hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:957)\n\t\tat hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1069)\n\t\tat hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)\n\t\tat jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.save(WorkspaceLocatorImpl.java:254)\n\t\tat jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl.access$500(WorkspaceLocatorImpl.java:80)\n\t\tat jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl$Collector.onOnline(WorkspaceLocatorImpl.java:561)\n\t\tat hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:697)\n\t\tat hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:432)\n\t\tat hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:154)\n\t\tat hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:294)\n\t\tat jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)\n\t\tat jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)\n\t\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\t\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device\n\tat java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)\n\tat java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)\n\tat hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:142)\n\t... 15 more\n
```

I am only interested to extract the following from the above logs.
**agent status**, **agent name**

Expected Result:

```
agent status: Unable
agent name: dot-dewsttlas403-ci
```

Comment: That's not a single line.

Comment: It is not a single line obviously. But after applying the filter it is a coming under one tag say @message.

Comment: `agent for (?P<agentname>[^ ]+)` and `agent for (?P<agentname>[^ ]+)` and `SEVERE: +(?P<status>[^ ]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it didn’t work for me. Can you be more specific or may be I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

`SEVERE: %{DATA:agent_status} to launch the agent for %{DATA:agent_name}\\n`

This should give you the result you are interested in, but it would only work if the structure of the message is the same.

Configuration used:

```
input {stdin{}}

filter{
    grok {
        match =>{
            "message" => "SEVERE: %{DATA:agent_status} to launch the agent for %{DATA:agent_name}\\n"
        }
    }
}

output {stdout{codec => json}}
```

Result:

```
{
  "host": "MY_COMPUTER",
  "agent_status": "Unable",
  "message": "hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher launch\\nSEVERE: Unable to launch the agent for dot-dewsttlas403-ci\\njava.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in /opt_shared/iit_slave/jenkins_slave/workspace\\n\\tat \r",
  "agent_name": "dot-dewsttlas403-ci",
  "@timestamp": "2020-01-29T16:54:27.256Z",
  "@version": "1"
}
```

---

Also to help you next time you're working with logstash-grok:

An online tester for patterns:
http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

The basic grok patterns: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try the same. I am using Herokuapp grokdebugger https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to test my patterns. I was facing issue with literal /n and /t.

Comment: I have tried your solution. It is working like a charm when I use the online grok tester but when I put the same grok pattern in my Logstash confit file, it fails. Can you suggest me a solution which will be the mixture of **regex + Oniguruma** ?

Comment: Weird, I've just tested in local and it worked. Anyway, converting the pattern I've written in regex: `SEVERE: (?<agent_status>.*?) to launch the agent for (?<agent_name>.*?)\\n`. I just had to replace the grok patterns with their equivalent regexes.

Comment: Another way to write the regex: `SEVERE: (?<agent_status>.*?) to launch the agent for (?<agent_name>[0-9a-zA-Z-]*)`. This time without the `\\n`, which might create issue with escaping characters.